# Username Mutiple MapRoute Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Salaam

I have been trying to use multiple `MapRoute` but I am not getting successful. My Scenario is this I am working on a project where user creates profiles and then shows the public preview of profile.

For public profile till now I was using default `id` 
Example:

> https://localhost:44300/Profile/DoctorProfile/alijamal14

Here 'Profile' is `{controller}` and 'DoctorProfile' is `{action}` and 'alijamal14' is `{id}` and this is working perfectly

I want to achieve a username route which would work the same even without mention of controller and action

> https://localhost:44300/alijamal14

For more information below I am mentioning my Rout.Config.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace DoctorSearchEngine
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Doctor", action = "Search", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "DoctorSearchEngine.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Users",
                url: "{username}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "DoctorProfile", username = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "DoctorSearchEngine.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /alijamal14
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

If I comment out first MapRoute Code localhost:44300/Profile/DoctorProfile/alijamal14 works but other controller and actions gets stop working

How can I achieve username after website domanname link along with default Route functionality?

Thanks

Comment: You cant (you could swap the order of the routes to make `https://localhost:44300/alijamal14` but then nothing else would). You need soething to make the routes identifiable

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Attribute Routing` to move the URL parameter configuration to your controller.

To enable attribute routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Doctor", action = "Search", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "DoctorSearchEngine.Controllers" }
        );

    }
```

Now, you can use attribute like this:

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{      
    [Route("{username}")]
    public ActionResult DoctorProfile(string username){
     ......
    }
 }
```